# Most efficient way to get a specific model from a collection in BLADE in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, model, eloquent

Hi im developing a site using Laravel and have some site data id like to keep track of such as facebook url, instagram url, address, phone number, etc. This information for this model is stored as a name and value in the DB, so example name:facebook and value:[facebook url here]. I know that i can retrieve all the models and get a collection, pass it to my view and loop through them, but id like a little more control to get specific models to use it where i need them on specific parts of the page. This is what I currently have it:

I have a model SiteMeta which i pass an instance to my view:

```
$site_meta = new \App\SiteMeta();
return view($page_string)->with('site_meta',$site_meta);
```

And in my SiteMeta Model:

```
public static function get($name)
{
    return SiteMeta::where('name', '=', $name)->firstOrFail();
}
```

And then in my view im getting my specific model by its name:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{$site_meta::get('Facebook')->value}}">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official data-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

So my question is, is this the most efficient way to do it? Im doing this in various places on the contact page to display information like phone number and address and other site information which i feel like is a bit overload as it make a request to the database each time im doing sitemeta::get('name');

Is there a better way to get a specific one from the collection in BLADE? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass it as an array from your controller method:

```
$site_meta = \App\SiteMeta::lists('value', 'name');

return view($page_string, compact('site_meta');
```

On your blade template you could do this:

```
$site_meta['Facebook'];
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a much better way. I voted up but it wont reflect until i have a higher reputation since im new to overflow. I appreciate it:)

Comment: @surgiie Glad I can help, if up vote doesn't work just click that "check" icon if you think my comment is answer your question :)

Comment: Yes it most definitely did answer my question :)